# The remote system is required to authenticate itself

Tags: linux, vpn, pptp

Почему у меня не получается подключится?

**Log**

```
pppd[26377]: The remote system is required to authenticate itself

pptpd[17816]: /usr/sbin/pppd: The remote system is required to authenticate itself

pptpd[17816]: /usr/sbin/pppd: but I couldn't find any suitable secret (password) for it to use to do so.

pppd[26377]: but I couldn't find any suitable secret (password) for it to use to do so.

pptpd[26376]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=559ff91674c0,len=8196) from PTY failed: status = -1 error = Input/output err

pptpd[26376]: CTRL: PTY read or GRE write failed (pty,gre)=(6,7)

pptpd[26376]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[26377]

pptpd[26376]: CTRL: Client 178.127.150.191 control connection finished

pptpd[26376]: CTRL: Exiting now

pptpd[17816]: MGR: Reaped child 26376
```

**pptpd.conf** localip - адрес в vpn или локальный? У меня стоит для vpn.

```
option /etc/ppp/pptpd-options

logwtmp
localip 172.16.100.1
remoteip 172.16.100.2-254
debug
```

**pptpd-options**

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
novj
novjccomp
nologfd
```

**chap-secrets** Не в двойных ли кавычках должен быть ip-адрес?

```
user pptpd pass 172.16.100.2
```

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1041155/178576)

Comment: «почему не получается» — вы сами написали прямо в заголовке: «удалённая система должна аутентифицировать себя». это перевод с английского на русский. можно ещё с русского на русский перевести: «настройте клиента правильно — чтобы он таки передавал аутентификационные данные. в вашем случае — логин, пароль, способ аутентификации и необходимость шифрования (всё это вы сами же и указали в приведённых вами же конф.параметрах)».

Comment: и — да. в предыдущем вашем вопросе я вам уже написал, что отладка pptpd вам (в данном случае) совершенно не нужна. а нужна отладка самого pppd. так что перенесите директиву `debug` из конфигурации pptpd в конфигурацию pppd.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Подскажите пожалуйста, а как просмотреть лог pppd? Я не нахожу службу вводя service status pppd

Comment: вы же его сами и привели — в первом листинге. первая строка — именно от pppd. о чём в самом её начале и написано.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Ничего не добавилось, кроме: pppd[5806]: pptpd-logwtmp: $Version$. У меня пропадаюг пинги когда я пытаюсь подключится к vpn, это как-то связано?

Comment: «ничего не прибавилось» — после чего? после того, как вы у клиента что-то поменяли? ну, значит, не то поменяли, что требуется, и клиент так и не отсылает всех требуемых вашим сервером данных.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin После добавления debug в optios ppp. Я указываю pptp, mschap-v2 и необязательное шифрование при подключении к серверу. Что мне делать?

Comment: «необязательное шифрование» — как же «необязательное», если сами пишиет в конф.файле — обязательное: `require-mppe-128`. нет, я конечно, согласен, что называть mppe шифрованием — это, мягко говоря, преувеличение: таким «шифрованием» можно разве что от офисных хомячков «зашифроваться». но со сложившейся у маркетологов терминологией спорить, увы, бесполезно.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Это означает - подключаться даже без шифрования...

Comment: это означает (буквальный перевод «require mppe-128»): «требуется шифрование по протоколу mppe-128»

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Я и указывать обязательное пробовал

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я 3 дня работал с /etc/chap-secrets... Все получилось

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать чтобы клиенты видели друг друга?